# Cakephp requested URL not found

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

i am using Cakephp1.3 on ubuntu 11.10

i create a table name users . i cake bake the application. and user_controller , views and models all are present.

Now when i am trying to acess **http://localhost/yps/users/** it gives following error

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /yps/users/ was not found on this server

Anybody have idea about this

Thanks

Comment: What's the exact filename of your controller file? You mentioned user_controller (without an s) but according to Cake conventions it would need to be pluralized. See http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/902/File-and-Classname-Conventions

Comment: did you check the file permission?

Comment: Could be an issue with mod_rewrite, perhaps this helps: http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/917/Apache-and-mod_rewrite-and-htaccess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Please follow the name convention, like @Joseph said
2. I encounter the same issue, it's caused by mod_rewrite, like @dhofstet said. Fix it, then everything works well. And how to fix it dependes on your web server's configuration. (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started.html#a-note-on-mod-rewrite)

Comment: You are right about RTFM to fix most problems... the link to documentation you shared answered my question in less than 2 minutes, a minute of which took me to figure out that I had to edit `/etc/apache2/apache.conf` instead of `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`

Comment: Hi ZZ Shao can u explain what I change in apache.conf file please its urgent